# How to specify that nullable reference type (return) is not nullable if argument is true

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have this C# code in a nullable context:

```
public string? GetValue(int key, bool errorIfInvalidKey)
{
    string result = <get the value identified by the key argument, or null if not found>;
    if (result == null && errorIfInvalidKey) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad key");
    } else {
      return result;
    }
}
```

If the caller specifies an invalid `key`, the `errorIfInvalidKey` argument specifies whether to return null or throw an exception. So, **this code is guaranteed to return non-null if `errorIfInvalidKey` is true**.

Is there a way to annotate this code to tell the compiler that a routine that returns a maybe-null will return a non-null if an argument contains a particular value?

Comment: I don't think so.  Part of the reasons I still dislike nullable reference types.

Comment: reference types don't need use nullable.

Comment: @TimChang Nullable reference types are new feature in C# 8 and higher that allows the compiler to warn us when code possibly accesses null references.

Comment: @NineBerry thanks I got it , this feature open my mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler stops at method boundaries. The signature of a method is a contract that the compiler relies on. For example, if the method and its caller are in two different assemblies, the implementation of the function could change without the caller being aware of that when the assembly is replaced by a different version. That's the reason why the compiler has to rely on the signature of the method to be correct without looking at its implementation for further information.

When the difference in behavior is so fundamentally different (return null or throw exception), use two different versions of the method instead of trying to control it through an argument.

The code that calls the two different variants of the method and the programmer writing that code will have to know beforehand what to expect (exceptions or null values) anyway, so it can already decide which method to use.

```
public string? GetValueOrNull(int key)
{
    string? result = <get the value identified by the key argument, or null if not found>;
    return result;
}

public string GetValue(int key)
{
    string? result = <get the value identified by the key argument, or null if not found>;
    if (result == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Bad key");
    } else {
      return result;
    }
}
```

---

There is a number of attributes that can be used to declare to the compiler how the internal logic of a method works so that the compiler can make assumptions about whether variables are null or not based on some other conditions:

[Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

However, none of it supports your scenario. But you could use the `NotNullWhen` attribute to replace the `GetValueOrNull` method above with one that follows the TryGet... pattern:

```
public bool TryGetValue(int key, [NotNullWhen(true)] out string? value)
{
    value = <get the value identified by the key argument, or null if not found>;
    return value != null;
}
```

This can then be used like this:

```
public void TestSomething() 
{
    if(TryGetValue(42, out string? value))
    {
        // No warning here
        Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
    }
    
    // Warning: Dereference of a possibly null reference
    Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
}
```

Comment: Good information, but it doesn't answer the yes/no question in the OP.

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health I've extended the answer.

Comment: And I've gone through my code and removed all instances of this pervasive code pattern (a parameter that decides whether to return null or throw an exception). Many thanks to NineBerry and Guru Stron for making a good case for why that code pattern is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to annotate this code to tell the compiler that a routine that returns a maybe-null will return a non-null if an argument contains a particular value?

No, there is no such thing, at least at the moment. The closest one is [`DoesNotReturnIfAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) but it will stop all the null checks after the call of method with corresponding value. I.e:

```
string? GetValue(int key, [DoesNotReturnIf(true)] bool errorIfInvalidKey)
{
    // ...
}

var v1 = GetValue(2, false);
Console.WriteLine(v1.GetHashCode()); // warning
var v2 = GetValue(1, true);
Console.WriteLine(v2.GetHashCode()); // no warning
Console.WriteLine(v1.GetHashCode()); // no warning !!!
```

I would argue that splitting method in two does not only resolve the problem but improves the readability of the code:

```
string? GetValue(int key)
{
    // ...
} 

string GetValueOrThrow(int key) => GetValue(key) ?? new InvalidOperationException("Bad key");
```

And usage is much more obvious - `GetValueOrThrow(1)` reads much better then `GetValue(1, true)`.